# "Request entity too large: limit is 3145728" when trying to update a k8s CR resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

We are hitting an error "Request entity too large: limit is 3145728" when trying to update a custom resource object.
That would be very helpful if any one knows how to change the size limit from k8s side.
Is there any exposed parameters for user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes object size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468110/kubernetes-object-size-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

Source for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492986/12153576

- The `"error": "Request entity too large: limit is 3145728"` is probably the default response from kubernetes handler for objects larger than 3MB, as you can see [here at L305](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/db1990f48b92d603f469c1c89e2ad36da1b74846/test/integration/master/synthetic_master_test.go#L315) of the source code:

```
expectedMsgFor1MB := `etcdserver: request is too large`
expectedMsgFor2MB := `rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = trying to send message larger than max`
expectedMsgFor3MB := `Request entity too large: limit is 3145728`
expectedMsgForLargeAnnotation := `metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes`
```

- The [ETCD](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/9925) has indeed a 1.5MB limit for processing a file and you will find on [ETCD Documentation](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/dev-guide/limit.md#request-size-limit) a suggestion to try the`--max-request-bytes` flag but it would have no effect on a GKE cluster because you don't have such permission on master node.
- But even if you did, it would not be ideal because usually this error means that you are [consuming the objects](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/3134#issuecomment-591278230) instead of referencing them which would degrade your performance.

I highly recommend that you consider instead these options:

- **Determine whether your object includes references that aren't used;**
- **Break up your resource;**
- **Consider a volume mount instead;**

---

There's a request for a [new API Resource: File (orBinaryData)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/88709) that could apply to your case. It's very fresh but it's good to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 0):

Check the files in the `chart` directory. You may have included some unrelated files in it!