# Error from server (RequestEntityTooLarge): Request entity too large: limit is 3145728 while creating a configMap

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, containers

I use `configMap` to feed the `init.sql` script to initialise my Mysql container in the Kubernetes pod. While that works for most cases I am struggling to convert a larger `init.sql` file which is 12.2 MB. 
I use the following in `deployment.yaml` to mount the configMap.

```
volumeMounts:
- name: init-volume
  mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

```
volumes:
- name: init-volume
  configMap:
    defaultMode: 420
    name: init-volume
```

The command I use to create the configMap

```
kubectl create configMap init-volume --from-file=init.sql
```

I get the error

```
Error from server (RequestEntityTooLarge): Request entity too large: limit is 3145728
```

How can I increase this limit/or any other alternate to initialise my database?

Comment: How do you access the kubernetes api server? is there a (reverse)proxy involved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012798/kubernetes-configmap-size-limitation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes object size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468110/kubernetes-object-size-limitations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I increase this limit/or any other alternate to initialise my database?

The `.d` nomenclature in that path means it will load **all** files found therein, so the solution is to chop up the `init.sql` into smaller chunks, name them so that they apply in the right order when viewed with `/bin/ls -1`, and stick each one into a configmap:

```sh
i=1
for fn in *.sql; do
   kubectl create configmap init-sql-$i --from-file="$fn"
   i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

then volume mount them into the directory

```yaml
volumeMounts:
- name: init-file-1
  mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file-1.sql
- name: init-file-2
  mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file-2.sql
# and so forth
```